# Rails: Ancestry + Acts_as_List Gems Not Working as Expected When Changing Parent Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry, acts-as-list

I have a Ruby on Rails 3 app which uses the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem to provide a hierarchical tree structure for a model in combination with the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem to provide explicit positioning within each level of the hierarchy.

```
class Obj < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_ancestry
    acts_as_list scope: [:ancestry]
    ...
end
```

Furthermore, I am using the following method on the object to change the parent of the object:

```
# Credit to the author of the ancestry gem for the code.
def move_to_child_of(reference_instance)
      transaction do
            remove_from_list
            self.update_attributes!(:parent => reference_instance)
            add_to_list_bottom
        save!
    end
end
```

Everything works as expected when:

- Changing the position of an object within the same parent.
- Changing the parent of the object when the object has no descendants.

**The issue I'm having** is that changing the parent of an object that also has descendants causes `acts_as_list` to not only change the position on the object but also change the position of all descendant objects as well. This causes the position of all descendant objects to act/be unreliable and incurs unnecessary database calls.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, or is this expected behaviour?

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though this issue is already know according to this [issue report](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/issues/131) and has a [pull request](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/pull/132) addressing it. As a short-term fix, I followed Brendon's suggestion posted to the pull request and got around the bug by declaring a custom scope thereby bypassing the `scope_changed?` method where the bug exists.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future save some time, and grey hair.

Comment: I'm running into this issue myself (the PR is still open). I don't suppose you still have the code around and could post a gist? I just added the two methods (`scope_condition` and `scope_changed` from https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/issues/131#issuecomment-210130196 ) and in my own tests it seems to make the issues disappear, but I suspect I'm missing something. Did you still have `acts_as_list scope: [:ancestry]` ? Did you write a custom `move` method?